# Is there any difference between a frame rate at a monitors refresh rate, and a frame rate above a monitors refresh rate?

Tags: display, framerate, refresh-rate

If my monitor has a 60hz refresh rate, should I be able to notice any difference whatsoever between say 60fps and 500fps?

Everywhere I read tells me that there's no difference, but I could swear I can notice something. As if the input lag is increased when I dip below, say, 80fps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not likely to notice a framerate above 60 fps, but you do notice if it ever goes below it. That's why 100 fps seems so smooth because you have a large buffer to drop down before you notice anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is also very important with LCD screens, is that you set up a game to sync to vertical refresh. If you do that, the monitor shows a complete frame 60 times a second. If you don't, it might draw half of the first frame, then half of the second, then 45 % of the third, then 50% of the fourth and so on. It will result in a horizontal "break" line that walks from top to bottom or the other way. That will look laggy.

So setting sync to refresh is way more important than having the proper refresh rate.